# Use only the pipe system without having to import TranslateService on every single component

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have ngx-translate all set up fine. But at the moment I have to import the "TranslateService"

```
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

on every single component in order to just use the pipe on the template, eg:

```
<div>{{ 'HOME.TITLE' | translate }}</div>
```

Is there a way I can prevent having to import it every time?

Comment: You're mistaken. Importing a service ina component is not what allows using a pipe in a template.

Comment: @JBNizet Ah ok. What would I have to do in order to use the pipe globally whilst avoiding any extra work in the typescript code of each component?

Comment: You have nothing to do to be able to do that. See this demo (originally from the ngx-translate home page), where I added a FooComponent using the translate pipe in the template: https://plnkr.co/edit/WIiZRuE8ou6EvU9nKa5x?p=preview. If you want help, post a complete minimal example reproducing your problem.

Comment: Ah your example there is perfect, thanks so much :)